# get certain element from each dimension in a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

How to get first element from each dimension in a numpy ndarray?

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']])
```

Result should be:

```
Result = ['a','d','g']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
  list( A[:,0] )
```

[Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) a numpy array will normally return another Numpy array, so you will need the list constructor if you *need* a list.

Comment: please explain the meanings of A[:,0] @dsign

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> A = numpy.array([['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']])
>>> A[:,0]
array(['a', 'd', 'g'],
      dtype='|S1')
>>> A[...,0]
array(['a', 'd', 'g'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

See [Indexing (basic) - NumPy Manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) , [Indexing - NumPy Manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

use the take function

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']])
print A.take((0,), 1)
```

Comment: what are the meanings of 0 and 1 in A.take?@lcfseth

Comment: it means that you want to get the first element ((0,)) (you can specify that you want the first and the third for example) along the (1) first axis.